# What does the second (object) parameter, { useNewUrlParser: true }, do when connecting to the database with mongoose.connect()?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I'm having trouble understanding what does the second parameter to the `mongoose.connect()` do.

```
mongoose.connect(
  "mongodb://localhost:27017/myDatabase",
  { useNewUrlParser: true }
);
```

Could you, please, let me know?

Thank you!

## What I've tried?

I've tried searching the MongoDB docs, the Mongoose docs, the Stack Overflow, and-of course-the web. I haven't found the explanation anywhere.

## Why do I care?

I'm working through the Get Programming with Node.js book and everything's going fine so far. However, I've decided to take a step back and inspect the book's provided code which contains a lot of code not introduced/shown in the book itself. I'm feeling lost due to the sheer amount of information presented in the last couple of days so I've decided to go through the book's code, line by line, and try to understand as much as I can before moving onward; otherwise, I'd feel as if I've learned when I'm well aware that I haven't. Conceptually maybe, but not in any real, practical sense.

Comment: _"the Mongoose docs"_... you mean these docs? [Mongoose.prototype.connect()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/5.x/docs/api/mongoose.html#mongoose_Mongoose-connect)

Comment: FYI `useNewUrlParser` was removed in v6. See [No More Deprecation Warning Options](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/migrating_to_6.html#no-more-deprecation-warning-options)

Comment: @Phil Yes. Ctrl+F search for "Url" returns 0 matches. Needless to say, Ctrl+F for "useNewUrlParser" also returns 0 matches.

Comment: I used the search in the left-hand sidebar ~ https://mongoosejs.com/docs/search.html?q=useNewUrlParser. Specific options aside, does the API documentation not answer your question? The 2nd parameter is connection options passed through to the MongoDB driver

Comment: @Phil Yes, but the book is using Mongoose 5 and I find it hard to believe that there's no documentation relating to the older versions. I must be missing something. Would you suggest not worrying about it and just moving on?

Comment: There's a version switcher in the left-hand sidebar too, at the top under the logo

Comment: @Phil Thanks! I'm disoriented from all the searching. Here's the answer I was looking for: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/5.x/docs/deprecations.html#the-usenewurlparser-option

Answer (score 0):

With the help from [Phil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/283366/phil) I've come across [this](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/5.x/docs/deprecations.html#the-usenewurlparser-option). Although `useNewUrlParser` is depreciated, for the sake of a deeper understanding of older codebases, I found it worth it and so might you.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).